# Facebook Feed Dialog - limit on Link size?

Tags: facebook, api, feed

I have a link that is 1068 characters long. The Facebook dialog appears but displays an error message: 
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: link too long

FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: "My post with a long link",
    link: "http..1068characters",
    picture: yikes.jpg,
    description: "Why not?"
    }, function(response) {
        if (response && response.post_id) {
            alert('Your Facebook post was published.');
        } else {
            alert('Your Facebook post was NOT published.');
    }
});

If I shorten my link to say, around 725 characters, everything works fine.
I can't find in the Facebook documentation, or anywhere else, where there is a limit on the number of characters that can be passed in the Feed Dialog "link" parameter.

Comment: Try 1023 and 1025. I'll bet it's a 1024 character limit, or possibly 768

Comment: Good idea. It looks like the limit is actually 1000 characters. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on 'trial-and-error' the (current) limit is 1000 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [DOC](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative), it's 1024 characters!